# AssignProcessToJobObject on Yeoman / Grunt and Compass

Tags: compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I've been trying to setup yeoman for a new project but when I start grunt compass I get:

```
$>grunt compass
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
AssignProcessToJobObject: (5) Access denied.
```

I've tried grunt server and it stops at the very same point.

My config is:

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
    relativeAssets: true
  },
  dist: {},
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    }
  }
},
```

I'm running it on Win7. Does anyone have a hint on what am I doing wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like someone posted the same problem at the same time.

Though yeoman recommends console2 it looks like v0.10.7 fails through this app. You should use cmd directly

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5505

Tested and working